# ¿Cómo centrar las letras para que no se salgan del slider?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

De la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que las letras no se salgan del slider que los contiene? 
Este es el código `html` que lo contiene:

```
<div  class="tp-caption font-weight-extra-bold text-color-light negative-ls-2 ws-nowrap"
                     data-frames=\'[{"delay":1000,"speed":2000,"frame":"0","from":"sX:1.5;opacity:0;fb:20px;","to":"o:1;fb:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;fb:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]\'
                     data-x="center"
                     data-y="center" data-voffset="[\'-60\',\'-60\',\'-60\',\'-85\']"
                     data-fontsize="[\'50\',\'50\',\'50\',\'90\']"
                     data-lineheight="[\'55\',\'55\',\'55\',\'95\']"
                     data-letterspacing="0">'.$compromiso['vCompromiso'].'
                </div>
```

Cabe destacar, que estoy usando el plugin de revolution slider y no directamente boostrap.

Comment: Utilizas Bootstrap? Si es así podés agregarle las clases col-sm-12 col-md-12 de acuerdo como lo explica en la página oficinal

Comment: Si utilizo boostrap, pero no funciona agregándole la clase mencionada.

Comment: Como dicen arriba puedes solucionarlo con las clases col-sm , col-md si es que utilizas Bootstrap. Te dejo un link con ejemplos simples para que puedas aplicar. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ponerle a todo el contenedor un `width` fijo, que lo acote al, por ejemplo, 100% de la pantalla, añadir `padding` al texto para que coja algo de aire y no se vaya hasta los bordes y además añadirle un `white-space: normal` para que cuando el texto ocupe el espacio que le has delimitado automáticamente salte de línea respetando las proporciones. Esto es un ejemplo:

```
  .claseContendor{width:100%; /*o tmabién puedes probar si te funciona mejor 'width:100vw'*/}
  .claseTexto{padding: 3em; white-space:normal;}
```